# Quickbooks Online - When a Sales Receipt is pulled in from Paypal, how to do you change the "default" product/service category?

Tags: quickbooks-online

When QBO pulls in data from paypal it creates a sales receipt and sets this category to "paypal sales" by default. Where do I change this to be something else?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also edit the Sales Transaction Form and change the account to the one you want and also change it permanently. It is very much like QuickBooks Desktop in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can just click on the edit icon next to the bank account and edit it from there.